# RDLC Grid Lines in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, rdlc

I'm using the RDLC Report Designer in VS2010 10.0.3 RTM release.

I'm trying to turn on the gridlines in RDLC design view.  I can turn on the rulers, but I can't seem to find the option to turn on grid lines.

Anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately they dropped the grid in the VS2010 report designer and replaced it with simlilar lining up/space between functionality you see in the Form Designer.

In my opinion this was a mistake as there are many times when you want to work on an "absolute" grid as opposed to lining up "relative" to other elements, especially when trying to replcate existing reports.

Answer (score 3):

I realize I'm posting an answer to an old post, but I was also looking how to do the same thing for my SSRS reports and tried:

Tools -> Option -> Windows Forms Designer -> General the Settings by default:

LayoutMode=SnapToLines
ShowGrid=True
SnapToGrid=True

The grid snap worked but no grid showed up.

The next best thing or work-around I found would be to also have the ruler show up so at least I could see where the snapping was taking place.

Next to the zoom dropdown on the designer is a ruler icon. Clicking that toggles the ruler on and off.

Hope this helps others trying to find a solution to the missing grid lines.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the blank section outside of the report, click View then Ruler.